# What should be done in order not to make an error while returning the json object or to be able to parse it properly?

Tags: c#, json, jsonparser

I am an intern now. I'm just learning coding processes. I am returning a data as json object. My developer manager said that a query or operation should be done so that there is no problem when parsing the Json object. What action can be taken?

He said it should be done before the parcel process. I thought of the try catch method. But I don't think this is the definitive result. What kind of query or code should I write before the parse operation? Here I am returning the data in excel as json.

My code:

```
Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense(_appSetting.ExcelLicense);
                byte[] excelData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                MemoryStream uploadExcelStream = new MemoryStream(excelData);
                //Stream uploadExcelStream = data.File.OpenReadStream();
                ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
                application.DefaultVersion = Path.GetExtension(fileName) == "xlsx" ? ExcelVersion.Xlsx : ExcelVersion.Excel97to2003;
                IWorkbook book = application.Workbooks.Open(uploadExcelStream);

                uploadExcelStream.Close();
                MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream();
                book.SaveAsJson(jsonStream, true);
                excelEngine.Dispose();
                byte[] json = new byte[jsonStream.Length];
                jsonStream.Position = 0;
                jsonStream.Read(json, 0, (int)jsonStream.Length);
                string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);

                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

                var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

                return Json(json2, "application/json");
```

When converting from Excel to json, I was told that sometimes there may be a problem with the parse process and I need to write a query just above it. How can I do something so that there is no problem?

Comment: I don't know what your manager is referring to. You might want to ask him. But I see you are creating a JSON string then parsing it to an object, then serializing it back to a string again. There is no point in doing that

Answer (score 0):

First up I think you could simplify the top part a little bit:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
//OR
var jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); //If you want to read async
```

As to your question, it´s a bit unclear what you are trying/supposed to do.

Since you are first desirializing your incoming json and then serialize it again to return, I can only assume you are supposed to do some kind of check on the object in between those two actions.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. I updated my question. Here to read the data in the excel file and return it as json. "Syncfusion" package is used to read data in excel file. Here, when parsing the data in the excel file and converting it to json, is there any problem? I don't understand what kind of error I can get while parse? In Excel, the data is read from beginning to end. But I was told that there may be an error in the parse operations when taking the data from excel and converting it to json. I was asked to write a code here before parsing.

Comment: @Burak try catch is likely what they want you to use. But honestly you should ask them.